# HTML does not render properly in SharePoint Hosted App with Angular 2

Tags: sharepoint-online, typescript, angular2

I am trying to create a very basic SharePoint Hosted App with Angular2.

App deployed successfully but it does not render the html properly. And I am stuck at this initial level only.
refer below output:

[image]

And below is my component code :

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1> test sharepoint app!!! </h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

below is a snippet of my selector:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

    <my-app></my-app>

</asp:Content>
```

I am just trying to render this one line of template.

Comment: Is this a SharePoint issue or an Angular issue? If you do this in a vanilla Angular app without SharePoint, does it behave differently?

Comment: With this same component and `<my-app></my-app>` selector code works perfectly when I write Angular2 App without SharePoint..

Comment: sorry I forget to mention that I am getting `fnRef.apply is not a function` error in my console.

Comment: I never tried Angular(2) in SP, switched to Vue. What you can try and test (to see if SPs parser is causing trouble)  is to save a normal (no ASPX code!) HTML file (like Derek says in the first comment) to your DocLib (and name it .aspx, because SP can't handle .html extension) and open that... that way SP should just behave as a IIS server

Comment: I updated the `angular2-polyfills.js` reference file to the `beta-12` version. And re-deployed my App. The issue is resolved and also I no longer see the error message of `fnRef.apply is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code working for me you can refer if you think it helps.

**HTML**

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<app-root></app-root>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

The below 2 files are in app folder

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<h1>Hello World, {{title}}</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent {
    protected title:string = "Venkat Konjeti";    
}
```

I am using this code in my sample SPFx web part. I hope the references and code might helpful to trace your problem.